# Base64 encoding in Java with LF and not CRLF

Tags: java, base64, encode

I'm trying to encode a byte array to base 64 in java. 
I need the exact same result like encoding in Python -
which adds newlines every 76 characters as per RFC 2045 .
The problem is that the new line is with  (b'\n').

Using encodeBase64Chunked from org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 results the encoded bytes with line separator, which, by default is CRLF (“\r\n”).
using the encoding of java 8 utils doesn't add this new lines.
android.util.Base64 is good but can't use it.
google.common.io.BaseEncoding encoded without the new line.

For now I'm using java.util.Base64.getMimeEncoder(76, LINE_SEPARATOR)
where LINE_SEPARATOR is \n.

But it's so ugly!

Does anyone know some other library I'm missing?

Comment: What is ugly about it? How could it be less ugly?

Comment: cannot you encode and remove the `\r` chars afterwards with a simple string replacement?

Comment: JB Nizet - I think there should be a function that adds only \n and not \r\n.  Jean-François Fabre - the getMimeEncoder put \n directly. No need in putting \r\n and then replace to \n only.